# Why a new white area pops up whenever I click on EditText in AVD?

Tags: android-edittext, android-virtual-device

I am developing android applications using Eclipse and I use an AVD to run it. From today whenever I click on any EditText in my app a white area pops up from under the screen with 'CAPS' and 'ALT' in it, and an icon appears at the notification bar.

[image]

I don't know why this happens and I don't did any thing to occur like this in my memory. After the appearance of this, am not able to clear characters using Backspace key sometimes(otherwise possible), which was previously possible. To delete a character or word I had to select it by dragging mouse over it and then typing new characters. How this problem can be solved ?

---

UPDATE :

Also I noted that this particular issue is happening only when I click on an EditText using mouse. If I use Tab key to move to next EditText from other this issue is not happening.

Comment: Have you tried setting your edit text input type to none?

Comment: @RyPope I set the input type of one EditText as number.